# Dialog editor with json export

Tags: graphs, json

Im interested in a dialog editor that allows to create dialogues for video games. It should allows looping of dialog options and to tag dialog nodes, with additional data(in example I could use it to make certain choices available only if the character has a certain skill score). It should export dialogues trees as json.

Also a general purpose directed graph tool would suffice if It allows simplicity of resulting json (i don't Need to know graphical information) or It allows exporting to json and custom data inside nodes (possibly allowing use of a template for each node to avoid typos).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://www.inklestudios.com/inklewriter and

https://github.com/InfiniteAmmoInc/Yarn and https://www.nevigo.com/en/articydraft/overview/ more video game focused but not free